# visits log via api matomo piwik

Tags: database, matomo, web-analytics, piwiktracker

need haltp with matomo piwik api, downloaded the api and searched for a way of getting visit log via api
Is there a way to get visits log of matomo via api?, what parameters it has?

searched in api functions havent found it